# How to solve $ab^2+b+7\mid a^2b+a+b$, $(a,b)=?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> $ab^2+b+7\mid a^2b+a+b$, $(a,b)=?$

Would you give me a hint how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your Question would be more intelligible if you used more words.  In any case it is not obvious to your Readers why the problem interests you or if you made any effort to research it yourself before posting.  Please review [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the elementary property of divisibility relation $x,y,z,a,m\in \mathbb{Z}$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
x\mid x \;\;\;\;\;\forall x\in \mathbb{N}\\
x\mid y \;\;\wedge y\mid x \implies x=y\\
x\mid y \;\;\wedge y\mid z \implies x\mid z\\
x\mid y \implies x\mid my\\
a\mid x  \;\;\wedge a\mid y \implies a\mid x\pm y\\
\end{eqnarray*}

However, you can find a solution to this problem here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h18491p124428

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $ab^2+b+7$ divides $a^2b+a+b$, then it also divides $b(a^2b+a+b)-a(ab^2+b+7)$.